# Turn XML column into SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have this problem that I don't know how to solve.

First I've imported the XML data to a SQL table named `Sheet1` to column `MENUXML`. A sample from the XML is:

```
<DADOSNOTAALTA titulo="Externa E6020731-INT NEFROLOGIA (27-10-2006*1:07:17 PM)" mostra="1" liga="novaalta.aspx?x=DADOSNOTAALTA" versao="1" data="27-10-2006" hora="1:09:05 PM" autor="CH" publica="" episodio="6020731" especialidade="SCI" interna="0">
    <DTALTA titulo="Data da Alta" valor="27-10-2006, 12:59" />
    <DESTINOT titulo="" valor="Consulta externa" />
    <DESTINOD titulo="Obs:" valor="HGSA 31/10/2006" />
    <MTADM titulo="" valor="DISFUNÇÃO ENXERTO RENAL&#xD;&#xA;CREATININA 1,4 -2,2 AGORA 1,7" />
    <RESUMO titulo="" valor="BIOPSIA RENAL - SINAIS DE NTA, SEM SINAIS NA MICROSC. ÓPTICA DE REJEIÇÃO AGUDA&#xD;&#xA; C4D POSITIVO PERI-TUBULAR" />
    <DIAGNO titulo="" valor="Transplante com rim de dador cadáver COM DISFUNÇÃO TRANSITÓRIA.&#xD;&#xA;Transplante pâncreas&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <TRATAM titulo="" valor="Tacrolimus 5 + 4 mg, 12/12 horas&#xD;&#xA;Sirolimus 2mg dia&#xD;&#xA;Prednisolona  20mg, manhã&#xD;&#xA;Valganciclovir 450mg&#xD;&#xA;Omeprazol 20 mg dia&#xD;&#xA;Bactrim                            1 compr./dia&#xD;&#xA;Epo B 6000 / 2 vezes /semana SC.&#xD;&#xA;Ácido acetilsalicílico 100mg dias alternados&#xD;&#xA;Carbonato de cálcio 2 gr,  /dia&#xD;&#xA;" />
    <PROG titulo="" valor="" />
    <PROPI titulo="" valor="" />
    <MONIT titulo="" valor="FUNÇÃO RENAL E PANCREATICA E NIVEIS FÁRMACOS" />
    <ORIENT titulo="" valor="cONSULTA EXTERNA TR RIM-PANCREAS" />
</DADOSNOTAALTA>
```

Then I've created a new table named `Dados` with the following columns:

```
dados_nota, destino_tratamento, destino_doente, 
metodo_admissao, resumo, diagnostico, tratamento,
prog, propi, monitorizacao, orientacao
```

These are all present in the XML.

[Table from where i want to extract the XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEemX.png)

[Table where i want to save the transformed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Wii.png)

Now the problem is that i don't know how to make SQL Server read the the XML direct from the column and transfer it to the columns in the new database.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

Your question might be clear for you, but it is not clear at all...

> ... they [columns] are all present in the XML...

Well, one might guess, but this is up to you :-D

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<DADOSNOTAALTA titulo="Externa E6020731-INT NEFROLOGIA (27-10-2006*1:07:17 PM)" mostra="1" liga="novaalta.aspx?x=DADOSNOTAALTA" versao="1" data="27-10-2006" hora="1:09:05 PM" autor="CH" publica="" episodio="6020731" especialidade="SCI" interna="0">
  <DTALTA titulo="Data da Alta" valor="27-10-2006, 12:59" />
  <DESTINOT titulo="" valor="Consulta externa" />
  <DESTINOD titulo="Obs:" valor="HGSA 31/10/2006" />
  <MTADM titulo="" valor="DISFUNÇÃO ENXERTO RENAL&#xD;&#xA;CREATININA 1,4 -2,2 AGORA 1,7" />
  <RESUMO titulo="" valor="BIOPSIA RENAL - SINAIS DE NTA, SEM SINAIS NA MICROSC. ÓPTICA DE REJEIÇÃO AGUDA&#xD;&#xA;                          C4D POSITIVO PERI-TUBULAR" />
  <DIAGNO titulo="" valor="Transplante com rim de dador cadáver COM DISFUNÇÃO TRANSITÓRIA.&#xD;&#xA;Transplante pâncreas&#xD;&#xA;" />
  <TRATAM titulo="" valor="Tacrolimus                 5 + 4 mg, 12/12 horas&#xD;&#xA;Sirolimus                         2mg dia&#xD;&#xA;Prednisolona              20mg, manhã&#xD;&#xA;Valganciclovir                  450mg&#xD;&#xA;Omeprazol                       20 mg dia&#xD;&#xA;Bactrim                            1 compr./dia&#xD;&#xA;Epo B                               6000 / 2 vezes /semana SC.&#xD;&#xA;Ácido acetilsalicílico         100mg dias alternados&#xD;&#xA;Carbonato de cálcio          2 gr,  /dia&#xD;&#xA;" />
  <PROG titulo="" valor="" />
  <PROPI titulo="" valor="" />
  <MONIT titulo="" valor="FUNÇÃO RENAL E PANCREATICA E NIVEIS FÁRMACOS" />
  <ORIENT titulo="" valor="cONSULTA EXTERNA TR RIM-PANCREAS" />
</DADOSNOTAALTA>';


SELECT @xml.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/@titulo',N'nvarchar(max)') AS dadosnota_titulo
      ,@xml.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/@mostra',N'int') AS dadosnota_mostra --some int value
      --ommited more attributes
      ,@xml.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/DTALTA[1]/@titulo',N'nvarchar(max)') AS dtalta_titulo
      ,@xml.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/DTALTA[1]/@valor',N'nvarchar(max)') AS dtalta_valor --bad datetime format, should be ISO8601...
      --The rest should work the same...
```

### UPDATE: Read from a table

Try this:

```
SELECT t.OtherColumn --add needed columns of your table
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/@titulo',N'nvarchar(max)') AS dadosnota_titulo
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/@mostra',N'int') AS dadosnota_mostra --some int value
      --ommited more attributes
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/DTALTA[1]/@titulo',N'nvarchar(max)') AS dtalta_titulo
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'/DADOSNOTAALTA[1]/DTALTA[1]/@valor',N'nvarchar(max)') AS dtalta_valor --bad datetime format, should be ISO8601...
      --The rest should work the same...
FROM YourTable AS t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot.
But what i would like to do is instead of DECLARE @xml XML = 'text...' i would like it to read from a Column in a Table. I don't know if this is possible, but it would save me a lot of time because i have 5000+ like this one.
Once again many thanks

Comment: In addition to the thank-you note, you should upvote this answer.  If you feel it completely resolves your issue, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: @Greenspark, thx :-D, but *Rui* will not be allowed to vote yet (needs 15 rep points). The acceptance will make me happy of course :-D (btw: without a `@Rui` in your comment there will be no alert...)

Comment: @Rui, see my update

Comment: @Shnugo really thanks for your help!
but now it gives an error saying i can't call methods on nvarchar(max)...
I've updated a 2 screenshoots for better understanding of my problem.
Regards